# VisualStudio | Create Project template from command line

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, msdn, visual-studio-templates

I want create `project templates` from command line. I have found an article on msdn (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc175307%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to use `Projectgen.exe`. I have `VisualStudi2017` installed. But I can't find the `.exe` on my diskDrive.

Does someone know how I can create `ProjectTemplates` from `command line` with `VisualStudio2017`?

**Here is a screenshot of the default wizard which I don't want to use**

[image: wizard]

Answer (score 0):

I was just faced with a similar issue. I could not find the `Projectgen.exe` application.

Confusingly, this was seemingly replaced by the `dotnet new` style of templating, though the original methodology for actual template creation from the Visual Studio application itself seems to be unchanged.

What is the way forward?

Well it looks like we have to create a Json file and specify which symbols to transform. This is basically what amounts to a big search an replace function, it seems.

More information can be found here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/04/02/how-to-create-your-own-templates-for-dotnet-new/

While I would prefer the old method, as it seems immediately easier to automate, this method seems actually more extensible in the longrun.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So what's the actual command we need to run?